# How to distort a jpeg on osx?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective, osx, distort

I have a photographed document that unfortunately is slightly in perspective. (Details: I took a photo of the document with Photo Booth but couldn't really make it perfectly vertical and no longer have access to the document) I need to distort it so that it looks as if it was perfectly vertical.

How can I accomplish this in OSX? I also have Adobe Illustrator and Photoshop installed

Comment: Later versions of Photoshop (since CS6?) have the perspective crop tool. That may help.

Comment: I have tried inserting the jpeg on illustrator, and then using free transform tool and envelope distort to distort them but I only change the border of the image but not the aspect ratio of the image itself

Answer (score 3):

You may use Photoshop which is better to correct your bitmap image distortion.

Either use Vanishing Point tools from Camera Raw but if the distortion got several VP's then you may use **Edit -> Perspective Warp**, if already available at CS6, or  **Edit -> Transform -> Distort**. Also there's the puppet warp tool since CS5.

So in the end you do have a lot of options to correct that.

Best.

H.

Comment: ...and lets not forget the keystone correction tool in Adobe Camera Raw, either. If you're using something older than CS6, JPEGs can be opened in ACR via Bridge/MiniBridge.

Answer (score 1):

[Affinity Photo](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/photo/) has a great perspective tool.

[image: Affinity Photo Perspective Tool]

I use it regularly for sketchbook and whiteboard captures. Be sure to set the `mode` option to `source` to do what you're after.

[image: Perspective options panel]

Comment: Good to see someone else is giving Affinity a try on here.

Comment: Exactly! And since your comment, they are bringing it to the Windows platform which was a nice surprise.  Hope it takes off, because Adobe has become WAY too complacent in their dominance, and has taken advantage of that fact.